# How spring picks up the implementation for interface at run time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wonder how spring data JPA framework picks up the implementation for the `JpaRepository`.

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there are two classes are implementing `JpaRepository`. Just taking an example.

I didn't see anywhere in the online demo examples indicating that use this specific class such that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @sairamch04 said is alright. I can only add, that when query is defined via `@Query` annotation or using standard jpa method name, a proxy object is created to execute the query. The creation of these proxies is within factory objects, such as `JpaRepositoryFactory` mentioned. Otherwise it falls back to implementation such as `SimpleJpaRepository`. For more information about repository, you can call `RepositoryFactorySupport.getReporitory()` method in spring-data-commons.

Answer (score 4):

To give a slightly broader explanation in case it is helpful.

When your application starts up Spring initializes the application context; i.e. the set of beans that make up your application.

As part of that (when `@EnableJpaRepositories` is present) Spring Data scans your classpath for all interfaces annotated with `@Repository`.  This will be the case when your repository interface extends `JpaRepository` (or `CrudRepository` or any of its derivations).

For each interface found it will register a "Repository Factory" bean.  A special type of bean that knows how to create others beans.  In this case, it knows how to instantiate an implementation for your repository interface.

The first time code is encountered that "auto-wires" your repository interface this triggers the factory bean to instantiate a special proxy class that (1) implements your repository interface and (2) targets an instance of the chosen implementation class, usually the `SimpleJpaRepository` (as @sairamch04 explains).  The proxy is the object that actually gets wired into your calling code (because it implements your repository interface).  Therefore, when you make calls to your repository interface you are actually calling the proxy and it forwards the call onto the implementation.  It can forward to other objects too depending on whether, or not, you have customized your repository or chosen to use QueryDSL.  But in the simple case, the calls are forwarded through to the implementation object `SimpleJpaRepository`.

HTH

Comment: Spring Data scans your classpath!! could you please tell me that class?

Comment: This code is called by `@EnableJpaRepositories` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/01fe39eab1ed7b768d0988cc1df699bc48aaa910/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java#L72.  `RepositoryComponentProvider` is a classpath scanner that looks for classes annotated with @Repository.

Answer (score 2):

Spring data uses `JpaRepositoryFactory` by default to find the right implementation for your repository. You can define a custom factory by the config `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class)`

Here's the way  `JpaRepositoryFactory` chooses the implementation

```
@Override
protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

    if (isQueryDslExecutor(metadata.getRepositoryInterface())) {
        return QuerydslJpaRepository.class;
    } else {
        return SimpleJpaRepository.class;
    }
}
```

From the source code of `isQueryDslExecutor`, If your repository implements `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, then `QuerydslJpaRepository` implementation is used.

```
private boolean isQueryDslExecutor(Class<?> repositoryInterface) {

    return QUERY_DSL_PRESENT && QuerydslPredicateExecutor.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface);
}
```